# Run sndvol.exe when volume icon is clicked instead of popup

Tags: windows-7, volume-mixer

Is there a way to open the Volume Mixer (`sndvol.exe`)

[image: sndvol.exe]

instead of the single-channel Volume Control popup

[image: single-channel volume popup]

when the icon in the system tray is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the tidiest solution, but you could whip up a small program with a tray icon (.NET has some nice classes for this) and have that start sndvol when the icon is clicked. Then you'd just have to run that at startup and disable the Windows volume control (I remember this being somewhere in the Control Panel).

Comment: Well, it definitely isn't the tidiest solution for me, as I've figuratively fallen through the cracks with development of .NET things, but I'll give it a go in either .NET or (possibly) C#.

Answer (score 0):

For MS Windows clicking the tray icon for sndvol.exe will open the single slider view then you tap the word "Mixer" (under slider) to open mixer view. You could create a shortcut to run `SndVol.exe -r 66323586` and assign a shortcut key, so this will give you a one-click to mixer view with all volume sliders. The "66323586" is a x,y position relative to taskbar location and **optional** (coordinate value = y * 65536 + x, where x and y - signed integers). I found the coordinates formula did not work as expected eg -r 10003586 was on far left and "SndVol.exe -r 3588" was far right of second monitor. I Tested on Win Vista, and I am assuming it is similar for newer windows versions.

If your Windows version is different this may help https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7948-use-old-new-volume-control-ui-windows-10-a.html about UI changes.